# SonarQube 4.4: use complexity as Color Metric in the Treemap of Components?

Tags: sonarqube, dashboard, treemap

Since recent versions of SonarQube, I noticed that the number of metrics available for the "Color Metric" setting of the "Treemap of Components" widget has become very limited, I am no longer able to use the Complexity or the Number of issues to color the treemap cells.

Is it a limitation of latest versions or do I need to do something to enable this?

Thanx

Answer (score 0):

The choice has been restricted to metrics with type `PERCENT` (4.0) then relaxed to include types `LEVEL` and `RATING` in later versions (4.3).

The rationale behind this is that unbounded metrics (such as number of issues, complexity) cannot be reliably mapped to a limited color range.

Comment: OK, I understand.
The possibility I have is to display the "Quality Gate Status" as Color metric, but I am unable such have such status evaluated per component: is there anything I have to activate?

Comment: I have the same question? Exists any solution or configuration?

Comment: No, the quality gate metric is only generated on projects/modules, not on individual files.